# How to select data from a row that has a value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating a social network that has an explore page. I want to show a post text or an image in two separate divs. The way it shows now isn't what I want.

It shows text and an image in the same div and if there is no image it shows a blank square where the image is supposed to be. It's an explore page so I want the post text and image to show up randomly and in separate divs and if there's nothing in the image div, it'll just show the text and vice versa.

[image: How it shows]

```
$explore_image = $con->prepare('SELECT body, image FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$explore_image->execute();
$explore_image->store_result();
$explore_image->bind_result($body, $image);

// output data of each row
while ($explore_image->fetch()) {
    
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
    echo "$body <img src='" . $image . "' id='explore_post_pic'></br><br><br><br>  
            </div><br>" ;
}
```

UPDATE!!! -

This code only shows one image and one div

```
$explore_image = $con->prepare('SELECT body, image FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$explore_image->execute();
//$explore_image->store_result();
//$explore_image->bind_result($body, $image);
$explore_image_result = $explore_image->get_result();

while ($row = $explore_image_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    //$id = $row['id'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    //$added_by = $row['added_by'];
    //$date_time = $row['date_added'];
    $image = $row['image'];

}           

// output data of each row
if (!empty($image)) {
    # code...

    echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' id='explore_post_pic'></br><br><br><br>  
        </div><br>" ;
}
```

Comment: [if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) (! [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty)($image))

Comment: what you mean by `This code only shows one image and one div`?

Comment: It only shows one div. And one image inside of the div.

Comment: Why did you drop the while loop? This is why it fetches only one image.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I just updated my code again and it still shows the same result

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$explore_image->store_result`.
See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). And do not forget to close both the prepared statement and the connection (in this order) after finished.
Based on your initial code:

```
$explore_image = $con->prepare('SELECT body, image FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$explore_image->execute();
// $explore_image->store_result();
$explore_image->bind_result($body, $image);

// output data of each row
while ($explore_image->fetch())
{
    if (!empty($image))
    {
     echo '<div id="rcorners2">';
     echo "$body <img src='$image' id='explore_post_pic'></br><br><br><br></div><br>";
    }
}
$explore_image -> close();
$con -> close();
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but fix this line `$con - > close();` to this `$con->close();`

Comment: Sure, a typo. I did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$explore_image = $con->prepare('SELECT body, image FROM posts ORDER BY RAND()');
$explore_image->execute();
$explore_image->store_result();
$explore_image->bind_result($body, $image);

// output data of each row
while ($explore_image->fetch()) {
    
    if($image!=''){
    $newImage="<img src='".$image."' id='explore_post_pic'>";
    }
    else{
    $newImage="";
    }
    
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">'.$body.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="rcorners2">'.$newImage.'</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Just tried this and it only shows `$newImage` and `$body` inside of the divs